# Why am I getting " void value not ignored as it ought to be"?

Tags: c

basically returning the value straight as "return pow((n%10),3) + arms(n/=10);" works but not passing it through another variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void arms(int n){
    int temp;
    if (n!=0){
        temp = pow((n%10),3) + arms(n/=10);
    }
    (temp==n)?printf("ARMS"):printf("NO ARMS");
}
int main() {
    arms(153);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would happen if use `arms(0)`? What would be the value of `temp`?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a number is an Armstrong number? Please edit the question clarifying the intent of this code and why you chose a seemingly recursive approach.

Answer (score 6):

`arms` is `void` which means that it does not return anything, yet you try to use it in your calculation:

```
temp = pow((n%10),3) + arms(n/=10);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is not valid. The compiler can't add `void` to `pow(%n%10,3)`.

A `void` function doesn't return anything but you as a programmer can't use it and expect the compiler to do the work for you, which in this case would be to remove the call to `arms`:

```
temp = pow((n%10),3);
```